# how to delete an array of files in php

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox

When checking several checkboxes, i grab all the values with `$_POST["checkboxes_delete"]`

Piece of the jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({  
            url:"",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{ checkboxes_delete:checkboxes_delete },  
            success:function(data){ 
            // and so on
```

In my php:

```
if(isset($_POST["checkboxes_delete"])) {      
  $result = $_POST["checkboxes_delete"];  
     print_r($result);
    unlink($_POST['checkboxes_delete']);
  exit;
}
```

When checking 3 checkboxes per example, `print_r` shows me the files, something like below:

```
uploads/image1.jpg,uploads/image2.jpg,uploads/image3.jpg
```

How can i unlink them all?

`unlink($_POST['checkboxes_delete']);` deletes only 1 file and works only if i check 1 checkbox...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if(isset($_POST["checkboxes_delete"])) {      
      $result = explode(",",$_POST["checkboxes_delete"];  
      foreach($result as $file){
        unlink($file);
      }
      exit;
```

}